# Regular Expression to swap nested quotes?

Tags: ruby, regex, quotes

I'm doing some text processing with Ruby.

For some text I'm working with: single quotes should never be outside of double quotes.  So, I'd like to craft a RegEx which matches single-quoted strings, but not those enclosed in double quotes already, so I can swap them with a script.  Make sense?

Thus, in the following examples, sentences #1, 2, 4, 6 and 8 are OK, while sentences #3, 5, and 7 contain incorrectly nested single quotes, which I'd like to swap:

1. This is a sentence.
2. This is a sentence "with double quotes."
3. This is a sentence **'with single quotes.'**
4. This is a sentence "with a 'nested single quote.'  Sometimes there are 'more than one.'"
5. This is a sentence **'with a "nested double quote." Sometimes there are "more than one."'**
6. This is a sentence "without a double 'closing quote,' which is common in this text.
7. This is a sentence **'without a single "closing quote," common too, unfortunately.**
8. I don't want to match apostrophes, however.  That won't work.

(bold face indicates the matches I'd like to make with the RegEx, so I can swap quotes.)

The point: I am trying to quote extended passages which already have quotes within them.  This requires me to swap their doubles with singles.

Is this possible? I've been trying for hours, and I can't seem to get it.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: To swap with what exactly? ie, what do you expect outputs of 3, 5 and 7 to be after transformation?

Comment: What's the difference between a single quote and an apostrophe syntactically? I don't see how you intend to be able to distinguish them.

Comment: Will there ever be more than one nested, double-quoted string?

Comment: To distinguish type5 without a human brain is harder. Do you have a stronger criteria?

Comment: How about several quotes in one sentence? Will there ever be something like: `this 'is' a 'string'`?

Comment: @sepp2k: Perhaps using `\B` or such. That was my initial idea.

Comment: @fge, I'd like to swap the quotes: 3,5,7 will have single quotes substituted for double, and vice versa.  But I'll do that in other code... the RegEx just needs to select the full clause.

Comment: @sepp2k, there is no difference... that's part of the problem.

Comment: @climbage, possibly, yes.

Comment: @jokester, what's type5?

Comment: @Lindrian, yes, that's possible.

Comment: @Lindrian But apostrophes can also appear at the beginning or end of a word, no? So even if you have something like `lala 'foo bar' lulu` it's impossible to tell whether those are single quotes or apostrophes without knowing anything about `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: @niteshade I mean the 5th example you gave.

Comment: @niteshade I don't think it's possible to distinguish between apostrophes and single quotes without some restrictions (like prohibiting words from starting or ending with an apostrophe).

Comment: @sepp2k, that's what I was going to do, if necessary: it's a quote if outside a word, an apostrophe if within a word.  That part I can probably figure out eventually.

Comment: @jokester, I can say it in natural language, with precision: a double quote, inside of a single quote, which is not enclosed in a double quote, unless that is also enclosed in a single quote.  There's some recursion here, I guess: I don't think it's trivial, but I think it's possible.

Comment: If you need to differentiate between identical characters(apostrophe['] and single quote[']), then you must build or use something that can interpret context. You know like a [natural language processor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing).

Comment: @RyanGates, yeah, you're right of course.  This doesn't have to be bulletproof, however... for a bigger project I might research AI, but it's a bit beyond what I need for this.

Comment: `Mr. Jones' car` is a possessive apostrophe outside of a word. Your best hope is to look for balanced pairs, but I don't think regular expressions, by themselves, will suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think regular expressions are the way to go for this one.  Why not just scan through the text yourself?

(pseudocode)

```
for each char in text

    if char is `"`, then ignore until next `"`
    else if char is `'` (and not part of a contraction), then capture until next `'` or `.`

end for
```

I foresee future issues with this.

Comment: Yeah, i see some issues too.  Maybe I'm just stuck doing it manually. :(  thanks for your help.  +1

Answer (score 1):

This might not be a perfect answer, but you could try using a `gsub` with something like this for #5:

```
a=> This is a sentence 'with a "nested double quote." Sometimes there are "more than one."'
a.gsub(/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z\s]*'[a-zA-Z\s]*(".*")[a-zA-Z\s]*'/) { |m| m.gsub('"',"'")}
```

For # 3 use:

```
a.gsub(/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z\s]*('.*')/) { |m| m.gsub('"',"'")}
```

etc. for the others.

These are just examples, but hopefully they help.  I think you have to be very
careful with this because depending on the data and regex you use, you can get
unexpected results and it may change your data in a way that makes things
worse. Make sure to get some rspec tests written and test with a very large
sample to play around with the best regex to process this with.

Another issue you may have is identifying sentences if they are in paragraphs.
It becomes much more complicated and you may need to use something like NLP to
identify them.

Additionally, you may consider using `chr()` and `ord()` in your code.

Good luck!

Comment: this is pretty helpful.  I'll check it out, and get back to you!  Thanks!